# Text links in ajax WITHOUT Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I have a slew of normal text links, and I want to be able to click them and send an ajax request to fetch the page, so I can dynamically load it into a different part of the parent page when I receive the html back from the server.
Because I am stubborn and like to know how things are done the hard way, I don't want to bother with jquery. I want to do this the sledgehammer way. But I can't find any comments on how to handle links with ajax not using JQuery.
I am a huge newb with all of this I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Why don't you look into the jQuery source and see how they do it?

Comment: See [this](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php) and [this](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajax-javascript.php)... there are millions more.

Comment: Note: The w3 shows how to do this with an onclick callback on a button. Can you put an onclick callback on a text link? I didn't think you could. If you can, this is all really simple.

Comment: I don't like to use a tool unless I understand what's going on under the hood. Tools are just that--they save time when doing something by hand is tedious. If you understand what you would be doing by hand, then you can better troubleshoot the tool and you know the actual mechanism to the technology and not just someone's easily replacable interface to it. Learn how to do something the real way and you are in a better position to use a tool effectivelyl.

Comment: @c0deNinja Maybe jQuery is easier and simpler, but plain javascript is faster. Maybe Rokujolady wants to maximize the performance

Comment: You can onclick just about anything nowadays.

Comment: This bit of performance NEVER matters when network access is involved. There is usually no reason for not using any function that simplifies the low-level XHR call. Doesn't even need to be jQuery.

Comment: @c0deNinja There is nothing wrong with wanting to skip JQuery for something as simple as normalizing the XHR object. In fact, older versions of JQ could be a holy terror with ajax if you were trying to do anything fancy with it.

Comment: @Rokujolady ***Please*** join us in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript we would appreciate your kind. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion is to attach a click handler to the link element and subvert the default behavior, e.g.

```
<div id="links_container">
    <a href="http://example.com/page" class="ajax_link">Page</a>
    <!-- etc -->
</div>
```

and in JavaScript..

```
// define the click handler
var ajaxLinkHandler = function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();// prevent browser from following link
    var link = e.target;
    var url = link.href;

    // I won't take the time to rehash standard JS AJAX here
};

// now attach the handler
var container = document.getElementById("links_container");
var ajaxLinks = container.getElementsByClassName("ajax_link");

for (var i=0; i < ajaxLinks.length; i++) {
    ajaxLinks[i].onclick = ajaxLinkHandler;
}
```

I like this approach because your HTML doesn't become hokey.

- For AJAX in pure JS, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Comment: Thank you. This answers a lot of questions.

Comment: @RokujoLady Now try it in IE8 and you'll understand more about why JQ got so popular in the first place. Stuff that would break off the top of my head: 'e' will be undefined (it should be an event object); e.preventDefault wouldn't work even if you set e to MS's global version of the event object (it just overwrites window.event) - It has some property you can set as a workaround, IE below 9 doesn't have getElementsByClassName (but IE 8 does have querySelectorAll surprisingly enough). Check out quirksmode.org if you're interested in all the old IE junk we've been normalizing for.

Comment: ^^ But the solutions are getting a bit dated. PPK's stuff was great in the day but he tends to normalize in the normalizing method repeatedly rather than define normalizing methods to suit the missing stuff outright before the rest of your JavaScript loads. I'm also a big fan of Dean Edwards, John Resig's blog, and you could learn a lot from understanding what JQuery is actually doing under the hood. Excellent approach to an adapter/decorator object factory.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to look up some of the following

- [Attach events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) to `<a>` tags
- How to prevent links from going to a page when you click them with [*event*.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault)
- [Selecting attributes](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domattribute.shtml) (like href) from an element
- How to use [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) without jquery (it's fairly easy)
- How to add the returned html to your current page using [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%3aelement.innerHTML)

In essence, select your `<a>` tag, add a click event to it. Prevent that click event triggering the link's default behaviour. Have the event fire an AJAX request to the page your link points to. Set the innerHTML of some element on the page to the contents returned by AJAX. You'll also probably need to parse out certain tags returned via ajax (the `<head>` for example).

In terms of the actual ajax request it'll look something like this:

```
//Taken (with modifications) from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

/**
 * 'standard' way
 */
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
/**
 * IE way
 */
else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
    try {
        httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e) {
        try {
            httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e) {}
    }
}

if (!httpRequest) {
    alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
    return false;
}

function testFunction(data) {
    alert(data);
}

httpRequest.onreadystatechange = testFunction;
httpRequest.open('GET', url);
httpRequest.send();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the javascript XMLHttpRequest object.
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlfile.asp

Comment: OMG I thought noone on StackOverflow would do that - NEVER link anyone to w3schools : http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @dievardump I don't think that w3schools is so bad, it has helped me lots of times. But sometimes is wrong or shows bad practices.

Comment: w3schools MUST be avoided in all case until they don't: accept to clarify they are not linked to the w3c and don't provide good examples. Did you even look at this page ? Code indentation, HTML in the JavaScript without any "templating" approach...

Comment: Cripes, it's not THAT bad. It just tends to be incomplete/outdated. No reason to beat down the one guy who actually mentioned the relevant object out the gate.

Comment: I wouldn't downvote the answer because it links to w3schools, Regardless of your feelings for that organisation, it's a good starting point.

Comment: Wow! Someone has a grudge. The question was answered, wasn't it? I didn't put up a neon sign directing people to an omniscient website that MUST be followed in their every move! I only answered one question. Also (@dievardump), the question had nothing to do with Good Practice or code indentation or HTML templating approaches, it was about AJAX. I believe I answered the only question that was asked.